# Covert this SQL function to inline

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datetime, stored-functions

Is it possible to convert this function to inline? I couldn't make it work. `dbo.session` table returns 100,000 records.

Gere's the logic of the code: the function returns number of hours per session. If the difference of startdate and enddate is more than a day and not more than a year, then it checks if Sat and Sun, adds hours counter by 24 hrs then set latest date to next day. Then after it also checks the latestdate if it is Sat and Sun, only add the counter if not Sat and Sun. Finally, final manipulation of hours counter from datetable.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[CheckHours](@startdate datetime,@enddate datetime)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @hours_count int, @latestdate datetime, @count int;

    SELECT @latestdate = @startdate, @hours_count = 0

    IF (DATEDIFF(hh, @latestdate, @enddate) > 0)
    BEGIN
        WHILE (DATEDIFF(hh, @latestdate, @enddate) > 24 AND @hours_count < 8760)
        BEGIN     
            IF (DATEPART(dw, @latestdate) <> 6 AND DATEPART(dw, @latestdate) <> 7) 
            BEGIN
                SET @hours_count = @hours_count + 24 
            END
            SET @latestdate = DATEADD(hh, 24, @latestdate) 
        END

        IF (DATEPART(dw, @latestdate) <> 6 AND DATEPART(dw, @latestdate) <> 7)  
        BEGIN
            SET @hours_count = @hours_count + DATEDIFF(hh, @latestdate, @enddate)
        END
    END

    SELECT 
        @count = COUNT(*) 
    FROM dbo.datetable dt
    WHERE dt.tdate BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate AND dt.tdate <> @startdate
    
    SET @hours_count = @hours_count - (@count * 24)

    RETURN @hours_count

END
```

The select query:

```
SELECT dbo.CheckHours(lastsessiondate, GETDATE()) AS CheckHours, lastsessiondate
    FROM dbo.session
    WHERE manucat BETWEEN 4 AND 9
        AND soloid IS NOT NULL
```

`dbo.datetable`:

```
+-------------------------+
|          tdate          |
+-------------------------+
| 2022-01-01 00:00:00.000 |
| 2021-12-25 00:00:00.000 |
| 2021-12-24 00:00:00.000 |
| 2021-11-25 00:00:00.000 |
+-------------------------+
```

result should look like:

```
+------------+-------------------------+
| CheckHours |     lastsessiondate     |
+------------+-------------------------+
|       3295 | 2022-01-14 12:01:24.147 |
|       3296 | 2022-01-14 11:55:18.893 |
|       3417 | 2022-01-08 10:11:22.243 |
|       3531 | 2022-01-01 16:04:16.050 |
|       3655 | 2021-12-25 12:01:24.147 |
|        524 | 2022-06-24 23:18:09.350 |
|        500 | 2022-06-27 23:03:21.987 |
|         47 | 2022-07-22 20:35:44.553 |
|         47 | 2022-07-24 20:33:36.710 |
+------------+-------------------------+
```

Maybe this will help? change the `GETDATE()` to `'2022-07-26 19:38:52.630'` then change the startdate to lastsessiondate  column above..

`SELECT dbo.CheckHours('2022-07-24 20:33:36.710', '2022-07-26 19:38:52.630')`

Comment: Some sample data (in a consumable format) and expected results will help us help you here; I'm struggling to work out your logic paragraph (maybe that the lack of coffee so far this morning).

Comment: What does `datetable` contain? Is it all dates or just working days?

Comment: @Charlieface it contains a lookup table like specific holiday date.  if the startdate is in the datetable, skip it.

Comment: You don't seem to be doing anything with it other than counting it. So does it contain every date or only holiday dates or only working dates?

Comment: @Charlieface added more details and the expected output. it only has the holiday dates.

Comment: *I can't make it work.* What goes wrong? Is making the function work correctly an acceptable solution to your problem?

Comment: What do you expect to do by making this function inline? It executes a very expensive `SELECT COUNT(*)...`. Even if you inlined that by hand, you'd get `SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ...)`. That's slow, because the query optimizer has no way of simplifying or converting that nested query simply because the nested query know nothing about the outer table. All those date calculations would prevent the optimizer from joining the tables anyway

Comment: What are you trying to do? What are those date calculations trying to calculate? It seems like the *outer* query should be the `SELECT COUNT` with filters coming from `session`. Date calculations can be simplified immensely and even eliminated if you use a Calendar table.

Comment: For example, all those `DATEPART(dw, @latestdate) <> 6` calls seem like attempts to exclude weekends. If you want to calculate work hours, a `Calendar` table with each days work hours would convert all this to eg `SELECT SUM(WorkHours) from Calendar where Calendar.Year = 2022 and Calendar.Quarter=2`

Comment: It looks like the entire query could be `SELECT lastSessionDate,SUM(WorkHours) from sessions inner join Calendar on Calendar.Date between lastsessiondate and GETDATE() WHERE ...`

Comment: I just wanted to make the function inline.. so it will not execute every row.

Comment: @O.Jones it runs slower for bigger resultset. :(

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, you want to calculate the number of hours from `lastsessiondate` to the current date (or `'2022-07-26 19:38:52.630'` for the purposes of sample data), but not count weekend (Saturday/Sunday) hours.

This can be done roughly by calculating the total hour difference and adjusting for week differences using the calculation `DATEDIFF(hour, start, end) - 48 * DATEDIFF(week, start, end)`.

What's left is to account for the edge cases where the start and/or the end date/time falls on a weekend. This can be done my advancing weekend start dates to 00:00 Monday and backing up weekend end dates to 00:00 Saturday (aka 24:00 Friday night).

Adding one or more `CROSS APPLY` clauses is a convenient way to build up successive calculations within a query.

The following code appears to produce results that closely match your expectations:

```
--SET DATEFIRST 7 -- Sunday = 1, Saturday = 7 (US English Default)
--DECLARE @Saturday INT = 7
--DECLARE @Sunday INT = 1

SET DATEFIRST 1 -- Monday = 1, Saturday = 6, Sunday = 7
DECLARE @Saturday INT = 6
DECLARE @Sunday INT = 7

DECLARE @Data TABLE (Id INT IDENTITY(1,1), ExpectedHours INT, LastSessionDate DATETIME)
INSERT @Data
VALUES
    (3295, '2022-01-14 12:01:24.147'),
    (3296, '2022-01-14 11:55:18.893'),
    (3417, '2022-01-08 10:11:22.243'),
    (3531, '2022-01-01 16:04:16.050'),
    (3655, '2021-12-25 12:01:24.147'),
    ( 524, '2022-06-24 23:18:09.350'),
    ( 500, '2022-06-27 23:03:21.987'),
    (  47, '2022-07-22 20:35:44.553'),
    (  47, '2022-07-24 20:33:36.710')

DECLARE @CurrentDate DATETIME = '2022-07-26 19:38:52.630'

SELECT D.*,
    DOW = DATENAME(dw, D.LastSessiondate),
    ADJ.*,
    AdjustedDOW = DATENAME(dw, ADJ.AdjustedSessionDate),
    CALC.CalculatedHours,
    Diff = CALC.CalculatedHours - D.ExpectedHours
FROM @Data D
CROSS APPLY (
    -- Adjust Sat/Sun LastSessionDate forward to Monday 00:00
    -- Adjust Sat/Sun CurrentDate back to Saturday 00:00 (Friday 24:00)
    SELECT
        AdjustedSessionDate =
            CASE DATEPART(dw, D.LastSessionDate)
            --WHEN @Saturday THEN DATEADD(day, 2, D.LastSessionDate) -- Incorrect
            --WHEN @Sunday THEN DATEADD(day, 1, D.LastSessionDate)
            WHEN @Saturday THEN DATEADD(day, 2, CONVERT(DATE, D.LastSessionDate))
            WHEN @Sunday THEN DATEADD(day, 1, CONVERT(DATE, D.LastSessionDate))
            ELSE D.LastSessionDate
            END,
        AdjustedCurrentDate =
            CASE DATEPART(dw, @CurrentDate)
            WHEN @Saturday THEN CONVERT(DATE, @CurrentDate)
            WHEN @Sunday THEN DATEADD(day, -1, CONVERT(DATE, @CurrentDate))
            ELSE @CurrentDate
            END
) ADJ
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT
        CalculatedHours = DATEDIFF(hour, ADJ.AdjustedSessionDate, ADJ.AdjustedCurrentDate)
          - 48 * DATEDIFF(week, ADJ.AdjustedSessionDate, ADJ.AdjustedCurrentDate)
) CALC
ORDER BY D.Id
```

Results:

| Id | Expect | LastSession | DOW | AdjSessionDate | AdjCurrentDate | AdjustedDOW | Calc | Diff |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3295 | 2022-01-14 12:01:24.147 | Friday | 2022-01-14 12:01:24.147 | 2022-07-26 19:38:52.630 | Friday | 3295 | 0 |
| 2 | 3296 | 2022-01-14 11:55:18.893 | Friday | 2022-01-14 11:55:18.893 | 2022-07-26 19:38:52.630 | Friday | 3296 | 0 |
| 3 | 3417 | 2022-01-08 10:11:22.243 | Saturday | 2022-01-10 00:00:00.000 | 2022-07-26 19:38:52.630 | Monday | 3403 | -14 |
| 4 | 3531 | 2022-01-01 16:04:16.050 | Saturday | 2022-01-03 00:00:00.000 | 2022-07-26 19:38:52.630 | Monday | 3523 | -8 |
| 5 | 3655 | 2021-12-25 12:01:24.147 | Saturday | 2021-12-27 00:00:00.000 | 2022-07-26 19:38:52.630 | Monday | 3643 | -12 |
| 6 | 524 | 2022-06-24 23:18:09.350 | Friday | 2022-06-24 23:18:09.350 | 2022-07-26 19:38:52.630 | Friday | 524 | 0 |
| 7 | 500 | 2022-06-27 23:03:21.987 | Monday | 2022-06-27 23:03:21.987 | 2022-07-26 19:38:52.630 | Monday | 500 | 0 |
| 8 | 47 | 2022-07-22 20:35:44.553 | Friday | 2022-07-22 20:35:44.553 | 2022-07-26 19:38:52.630 | Friday | 47 | 0 |
| 9 | 47 | 2022-07-24 20:33:36.710 | Sunday | 2022-07-25 00:00:00.000 | 2022-07-26 19:38:52.630 | Monday | 43 | -4 |

See this [db<>diddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=341f7c6fae69a84405b87e3cc64b273c).

Differences between expected and actual results may be the result of your original weekend adjustment skipping entire 24 hour periods instead of skipping up to the start of the week (Monday 00:00).

The current (end) date adjustment can actually be pulled out of the query. The `CROSS APPLY`s can also be eliminated by successive substitution, but the results will contain redundant subexpressions and be likely very hard to read.

I'll leave it to you to review and tweak the results.

Extending this to also skip holidays would expand the logic along similar lines. For holidays in the middle of the range, this can be handled by simply counting the holidays and adjusting the result by 24 hours for each. The trick is adjusting the start and end date/times. This is complicated by the fact that holidays can be adjacent to weekends and to other holidays. Potentially you could have a sequence like Holiday-Holiday-Saturday-Sunday-Holiday to account for.

My suggestion would be to expand your holiday date table (or build an intermediate temporary table) to not only include the date of the holiday, but also the pre-calculated last workday before and the first workday after each. This could then be used to match and adjust start and end dates in an extra step before applying the regular weekend adjustment. If you would like me to expand on this, drop a comment and I may be able to post a more complete example.